# clickable div javascript programming

Tags: javascript

I have 5 divs and I want each of them to be clickable and change the background and content in the div "new"

```html
<div class="new"><b></b>
  <button id="btn">Przeczytaj Artykułt</button>
  <div class="card" id="pierwszy"><img src="img/slajd1.png"></div>
  <div id="next">&rang;</div>
  <div id="prev">&lang;</div>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
<div class="dol">
  <div class="card" id="pierwsz"><img src="slajdy/slajd1.png"></div>
  <div class="card" id="drugi"><img src="slajdy/slajd2.png"></div>
  <div class="card" id="trzeci"><img src="slajdy/slajd3.png"></div>
  <div class="card" id="czwarty"><img src="slajdy/slajd4.png"></div>
  <div class="card" id="piaty"><img src="slajdy/slajd5.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you with relevant code you tried

Answer (score 2):

First, you appear to have one `.card` element that doesn't go with the others. I'm assuming you want to only update `.new` when any of the *other* five `.card` elements are clicked, so for the purposes of my example, I've removed that element. You can always use `.dol > card` as a selector if need be :)

Assuming you want to change the background of `.new` when you click on any element with the class `card`, what you'll want to do is first collect all of the elements with the class `card`, which can be done with **[`document.getElementsByClassName('card')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)**.

You'll also need to define the target `.new` element, with `document.getElementsByClassName('new')[0]`. Note the `[0]` at the end of the selector, which indicates that we want the first result. This is important because `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements, and even if there is only one result, we need to explicitly state that we want to use that one.

Now that you have both the cards and the target defined, you'll want to loop over each of the card elements, attaching an `onclick` event handler to each one. The `for` loop would be `for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)`, and the handler would be added with `cards[i].onclick = function() { }`.

For each of the card elements, you want to modify the **[`style.background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)** of to change the background colour, and the **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** to change the content.

The brackets and the `i` at the end of the function are an **[immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)**, which gets run as soon as the page is loaded. This is needed to attach the event handlers.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
var newElement = document.getElementsByClassName('new')[0];
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)(function(i) {
  cards[i].onclick = function() {
    newElement.style.background = 'red';
    newElement.innerHTML = 'modified';
  }
})(i);
```

```html
<div class="new"><b></b>
  <button id="btn">Przeczytaj Artykułt</button>
  <div id="next">&rang;</div>
  <div id="prev">&lang;</div>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
<div class="dol">
  <div class="card" id="pierwsz"><img src="slajdy/slajd1.png"></div>
  <div class="card" id="drugi"><img src="slajdy/slajd2.png"></div>
  <div class="card" id="trzeci"><img src="slajdy/slajd3.png"></div>
  <div class="card" id="czwarty"><img src="slajdy/slajd4.png"></div>
  <div class="card" id="piaty"><img src="slajdy/slajd5.png"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Correct; good spotting! I'll update my answer to correct that :)

Answer (score 0):

This can do it

```js
function ChangeBackground(incomingDiv)
      {
       incomingDiv.style.background = "green";
    incomingDiv.innerHTML = "the original text wasn't good enough";
      }
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <title>Document</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div id="div1" onclick="ChangeBackground(this);">blah blah blah</div>
      <div id="div2" onclick="ChangeBackground(this);">bleh bleh bleh</div>
      <div id="div3" onclick="ChangeBackground(this);">blue blue blue</div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

This method works too, and it shows how to discriminate between elements

```js
function ChangeBackground(incomingDivId) {
    var theclickeddiv = document.getElementById(incomingDivId);
    switch (incomingDivId) {
        case "div1":
            theclickeddiv.style.background = "green";
            theclickeddiv.innerHTML = "new text for div1"
            break;
        case "div2":
            theclickeddiv.style.background = "orange";
            theclickeddiv.innerHTML = "new text for div2"
            break;
        case "div3":
            theclickeddiv.style.background = "purple";
            theclickeddiv.innerHTML = "new text for div3"
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="ChangeBackground(this.id);">blah blah blah</div>
<div id="div2" onclick="ChangeBackground(this.id);">bleh bleh bleh</div>
<div id="div3" onclick="ChangeBackground(this.id);">blue blue blue</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan, because I never looked up how to use it. But now that you mention it, I'll get informed and edit my answer. Thank you

Comment: [a more relevant link](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would have been more appropriate though